# Calculating if mouse position is within bounds of a diamond polygon

Tags: java, mouseover, point-in-polygon

I have a diamond drawn on a panel and I'm trying to calculate if the mouse position is within its bounds. The problem is trying to the diamond, it needs four coordinates making up four lines to create the shape.[image: diamond]

The easy thing to do is to create/fit a square within the bounds of the diamond, but I want to account for the remaining triangular areas outside. I initially thought I trying to calculate the slope between two points and figuring out if the x and y of the mouse intersects the line by adding the slope into the the equation, but it proved to be a lot more difficult when it comes to the lines that make up the TOP->RIGHT, RIGHT->BOTTOM and BOTTOM->LEFT given that the center of the diamond is not zero.

Is there an easier implementation to check if the mouse's x,y is within the bounds of the diamond?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716378/pixel-coordinates-on-diamond

Comment: If the diamond width and height are equal this is trivial.  Just take the difference from the diamond center and your point.  If not, try treating the diamond as 2 triangles, and doing a triangle hit test instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudo-code (to be more readable):

```
Point org = new Point(64, 32); // Center.
Point radii = new Point(32, 16); // Half the size.

Point mousePos = ...

mousePos -= org; // Relative to the center.
boolean inside = Math.abs(mousePos.x) * radii.y + Math.abs(mousePos.y) * radii.x
                 <= radii.x * radii.y;
```

Of math one knows (0, radii.y) and (radii.x, 0) determine the border line in the positive quadrant.
That comes down to the formula above.

```
static boolean isInsideDiamond(int x, int y, int[] xs, int[] ys) {
    int minX = xs[0];
    int maxX = minX;
    int minY = ys[0];
    int maxY = minY;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
        minX = Math.min(minX, xs[i]);
        maxX = Math.max(maxX, xs[i]);
        minY = Math.min(minY, ys[i]);
        maxY = Math.max(maxY, ys[i]);
    }

    int orgX = (minX + maxX) / 2;
    int orgY = (minY + maxY) / 2;
    int radX = (maxX - minX) / 2;
    int radY = (maxY - minY) / 2;

    return isInsideDiamond(x, y, orgX, orgY, radX, radY);
}

static boolean isInsideDiamond(int x, int y, int orgX, int orgY, int radX,
        int radY) {
    x -= orgX;
    x = Math.abs(x);
    y -= orgY;
    y = Math.abs(y);
    return x * radY + y * radX <= radX * radY;
}
```

---

By the way:

```
Polygon diamond = new Polygon(xs, ys, 4);
boolean inside = diamond.contains(x, y);
```

Comment: I like how it avoids division and floating points and the similarity to an "is in circle" test is also nice.

Comment: I've separated the code that just found the centre and dimensions of the diamond from the real calculation code. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I am glad you picked up the code. That always is nice.

Comment: @JoopEggen Isn't your method really checking against the ellipse enclosing the diamond, instead only the diamond?

Comment: @Durandal no, you are thinking of `ax² + by² = c`. Here I scale both x and y to `radX*radY` so that for the scaled x and y: `x+y == c` would be a -45° diagonal through (0, c) and (c, 0). And `x+y <= c` would fill the triangle.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes, I was thinking along the lines of the pythagorean theorem, thanks to your explanation I caught on to the difference that here its scaling, not squaring. Thanks for showing me how this geometrically works.